# symfony2, img doesn't show

Tags: image, symfony

In my twig template I have

```
<img scr="{{ asset('bundles/jbamain/images/kanren1.png') }}" />
```

At runtime it becomes

```
<img scr="/jba/php/web/bundles/jbamain/images/kanren1.png" />
```

If I browse to

```
http://localhost/jba/php/web/bundles/jbamain/images/kanren1.png
```

then, the image is returned as expected.

However, the page, which has the  tag doesn't show the image. I set image file permission to 664. Also I set image width and height in css, but still the same. What may cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in image attribute [src](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp). So change scr -> src